# Capture all dots surrounded by certain xml tags

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML data that I need to reformat as it gives me a clock with dots and I want to replace those dots with : instead.
But I only want to do it inside of "FromTime" to "/ToTime" as it can be dots other places in the xml that are valid.

```
<PresenceData>
    <Presence>
        <Date>2020-01-19</Date>
        <FromTime>15.00.00</FromTime>
        <ToTime>22.15.00</ToTime>
        <Description>Sunny day.</Description>
    </Presence>
    <Presence>
        <Date>2020-01-28</Date>
        <FromTime>15.00.00</FromTime>
        <ToTime>22.15.00</ToTime>
        <Description>bla bla bla.. bla.</Description>
    </Presence>
</PresenceData>
```

Is regex the way to go here?

Comment: You could make use of an xml parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8). Get the value of that node and replace `.` with `:`.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var projectPath = "Path to your xml file";
xmlDoc.Load(projectPath);

var fromNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Presence/FromTime");
if (fromNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromNode.InnerText))
{
    fromNode.InnerText = fromNode.InnerText.Replace(".", ":");
}

var toNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Presence/ToTime");
if (toNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toNode.InnerText))
{
    toNode.InnerText = toNode.InnerText.Replace(".", ":");
}

xmlDoc.Save(projectPath);
```

Comment: That worked great, for the first element (SelectSingleNode) - so only need a way to iterate through all the elements.

Comment: Looks like using xmlDoc.SelectNodes and a for loop over fromNodes/toNodes worked! Thanks a bunch!